# How to support multiple roles with NextAuth and Next.js Middleware?

Tags: next.js, middleware, next-auth

I have three roles for my Next.js application using NextAuth: *user, company,* and *admin*. I want to be able to secure certain routers to their specific roles using middleware.

Examples:

- Sign In and Sign Up pages should not be accessible if an account is logged in
- /profile, should only be accessible by a signed in account that has the user role.
- /company, /api/company, etc. should only be accessible for a signed in account that has a company role.
- /admin, /api/admin, etc. should only be accessible for a signed in account that is an admin.

Below is the middleware file that I am currently using which I am having problems with. I am running into an issue when an account with the wrong role tries to access a protected path, such as a company account trying to access /admin. It currently just redirects them to the /login page.

Is there a way to redirect users to a different page instead of forcing them to the login screen?

**middleware.ts**

```
import { withAuth } from "next-auth/middleware";
import { NextRequest } from "next/server";
import { RoleType } from "./types";

export default withAuth({
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    authorized({ req, token }: { req: NextRequest; token: any }) {
      const pathName = req.nextUrl.pathname;

      if (pathName.includes("admin") && token.role !== RoleType.ADMIN) {
        return false;
      }

      if (pathName.includes("company") && token.role !== RoleType.COMPANY) {
        return false;
      }

      if (pathName.includes("profile") && token.role !== RoleType.USER) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    },
  },
});

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    "/profile",
    "/company/:path*",
    "/api/company/:path*",
    "/admin/:path*",
    "/api/admin/:path*",
  ],
};
```